# Is spaced repetition more “efficient” at creating leeches?

Tags: spaced-repetition

I’ve found spaced repetition a by and large useful tool for memorisation, but I have a suspicion that it does a “good” job of reinforcing memories you “know” are incorrect (you get them wrong when reviewing, and soon you remember that you keep getting the flash card wrong), not just ones you know are correct.

What is known about spaced repetition creating what anki dubs “leeches” - something you get wrong repeatedly, probably not because of a total absence of memories, but instead the presence of memories that are not correct? For example, is it known whether conventional SRS algorithms are “better” at creating leeches than a system which has purely random intervals between a card being revised?